# How to change value of cell in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, cell, worksheet

I'm trying to replace the value of a cell in the "Visualizer" sheet with the value of a cell in the "Automater" worksheet. However, nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
Sub RepForm_Click()
    Dim visualizer3 As Worksheet, automater As Worksheet

    Set visualizer3 = Sheets("Visualizer")
    Set automater = Sheets("Automater")
    Range("C22").Value = Range("D24").Value <-- Replaces a cell in the same sheet, works perfectly
    visualizer3.Range("E2").Value = Range("D24").Value <-- Replaces a cell in a different sheet, doesn't work
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify your ranges... you didn't specify `automater.range()`.

```
Sub RepForm_Click()
    Dim visualizer3 As Worksheet, automater As Worksheet
    Set visualizer3 = Sheets("Visualizer")
    Set automater = Sheets("Automater")
    visualizer3.Range("E2").Value = automater.Range("D24").Value
End Sub
```

---

Edit1:  Updated cell reference on `visualizer3` from `C22` to `E2`.

Comment: It doesn't work, nothing happens.

Comment: "Nothing happens"... you've verified that `automater.Range("D24").Value` has a value in it, or does not already contain the same value as `visualizer3.Range("C22").Value`?

Comment: Yes to both (and I'm actually changing cell visualizer.E2, the C22 was the one that was working correctly and that is on the same sheet as D24 (Automater). )
Image: https://imgur.com/a/xJO0Cjr

Comment: @HugoAlmeida just to verify, you've updated in your use of the code to take `visualizer3.Range("E2").Value = automater.Range("D24").Value`?

Comment: @HugoAlmeida from your screenshot... your sheet name is `formations`.  is that the issue?  `sheets("formations").Range("E2").Value = automater.Range("D24").Value`

Comment: That was the problem... Sorry I should pay more attention. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Change the code including the parent sheets and the Workbook of the ranges you are dealing with:

```
   Option Explicit

    Sub RepForm_Click()
        Dim visualizer3 As Worksheet, automater As Worksheet
    
        Set visualizer3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Visualizer")
        Set automater = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Automater")
        visualizer3.Range("C22").Value = visualizer3.Range("D24").Value
        automater.Range("E2").Value = visualizer3.Range("D24").Value
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, nothing happens.

Comment: You have to enter in the Debug mode: on the VBE click in the second "Set", then press F9 to put a 'Stop' on this line when running it. Run the code and then the execution stops there. At this moment you press, line by line, F8. On each press check/inspect the state of the variables (hovering the mouse on it, or, as an example, Debug.Print automater.name, so you can detect what's wrong with it. In my example, change this line "automater.Range("E2").Value = visualizer3.Range("D24").Value" by "visualizer3.Range("E2").Value = automater.Range("D24").Value" I guess is that what you would do.